# How do I use the flaming and explosive arrows on Far Cry 4?

Tags: xbox-360, far-cry-4

I just got enough skill points to get the Trade Agreement skill on Far Cry 4. Soon after, I purchased the six [flaming arrows](http://farcry.wikia.com/wiki/Flame_Arrow), six [explosive arrows](http://farcry.wikia.com/wiki/Explosive_Arrow) and six normal arrows. Well I was looking around on screen after pulling out my recurve bow and to my utter surprise I noticed that there is no button on screen to tell me how to switch arrows. I play this on 360 btw if that helps. How do I use my new arrows?

Answer (score 5):

If you open up your weapon wheel and 'hover' over your bow, you can press X or Y to choose between the arrow types.

Edit- Push X while your bow is equipped to switch back to regular arrows!

Comment: Exactly correct. I enjoy nothing more than sneaking up on an unassuming group of Pagan's soldiers, as they huddle confused around the rock I just tossed in, or animal I bated over to them, and blasting them to smithereens with what amounts to a grenade on an arrow. Fire arrows are also handy for those forgotten or hard to reach posters!